# How to convert string to list of dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I have a string from http response

```
data = "[{'value':123,'Type':'Range'},{'value':456,'Type':'Fixed'}]"
```

how can i convert it into list of dict in c#

Comment: That string is [almost, but not quite, entirely unlike JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Not_entirely_unlike). Are you sure it uses single quotes and not double quotes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure single quote instead of double quote will be no issue for Json.net

Comment: The main issue for me is the expected result:  "list of dict". Do you mind explaining a little bit more? Why dictionary if it has only 2 key that are always the same. it really look like a List object to me.

Comment: Just Deserialize it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bIPFfX.

Comment: @canton7, It seems that finding a parser that is strict to the RFC is hard. The strict mode has been a request from 2015 https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/646.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no issue there.

With either [deserialising](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm) it to `List<customObject>` or `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`
using [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

```
public class Data{
    public string value{get;set;}
    public string Type{get;set;}
}

var testClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(input);
```

Object dump:

```
Dumping object(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data])  
[  
   {  
       Type   : Range  
       value  : 123  
   },  
   {  
       Type   : Fixed  
       value  : 456  
   }  
]
```

Or directly :

```
var testDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>(input);
```

Result :

```
Dumping object(  
  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[String,String]])  
[  
   {  
    [  
           [value, 123]  
           ,  
           [Type, Range]  
    ]   },  
       {  
    [  
           [value, 456]  
           ,  
           [Type, Fixed]  
    ]     
   }  
]
```

Don't forget the `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rXwkhV)

Comment: how can i convert  ['key1':{'name':'as', 'age':'25'},'key2': {'name':'sd', 'age':'25', 'qwed':'qwe'}]

Comment: @Iceberg, not a valid Json. https://www.json.org/json-en.html. It start with an [. So it's an array but the value inside it is `"key1":{"name":"as", "age":"25"}`. Thats either missing the `{}` for it to be an object or totaly not an array to begin with so the `[]` must be turn into `{}`

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use simple list of object :
First create class like below

```
     public class respObject
     {
       public int Value { get; set; }
       public string  Type { get; set; }
     }
```

then DeserializeObject  using Newtonsoft.Json
as

```
        var data = "[{'value':123,'Type':'Range'},{'value':456,'Type':'Fixed'}]";

        var objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<respObject>>(data);
```

But answer to your Question list of dict

```
         var data = "[{'value':123,'Type':'Range'},{'value':456,'Type':'Fixed'}]";

         var listDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(data);
```

Comment: how can i convert ['key1':{'name':'as', 'age':'25'},'key2': {'name':'sd', 'age':'25', 'qwed':'qwe'}]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `JArray`

```
var data = "[{'value':123,'Type':'Range'},{'value':456,'Type':'Fixed'}]";
var dict = JArray.Parse(data)
                 .ToDictionary(k => k["value"].ToString(), v => v["Type"].ToString());
```